# Python .exe failed to work at a PC with no Python env

Tags: python, exe, python-3.7

I have created a simple python .exe file and shared it across to people who don't have Python environment on their system. One of my colleagues is getting the below error:

The code execution cannot proceed because python37.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

The .exe is created using cx-freeze. Is there any additional configuration I need to do or any alternative method of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method: Use pyinstaller to generate an .exe:

```
scripts/pyinstaller hello.py
```